# Dynamica Mathematica package for the book "Discrete Dynamical Systems and Difference Equations with Mathematica" by Kulenovic and Merino

Tags: graphics

Cannot download the package from http://www.math.uri.edu/Dynamica/ (shows a 404 Not found error), can someone send me the package in a .zip file?
I have the book, the book refers to the above link to download the package, but the link shows nothing, I have tried to contact the authors but no response.

thanks

Comment: You’re likely to have better luck with such a request on the wolfram community website. As it stands, this question is not appropriate for this stack exchange site.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2227692).